# Additional Repositories property for Gitpod in gitpod.yml file not working

Tags: gitpod

I am setting up a workspace in gitpod where I need to checkout additional repository like [multirepo example](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/multi-repo). I have added this property in my .gitpod.yml file however when setting up container image it is not checking out the additional repo. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my yml file?

```
additionalRepositories:
  - url: https://github.mycorp.com/repo1
  - url: https://github.mycorp.com/repo2
tasks:
  - name: start-workspace
    init: .gitpod/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. With additionalRepositories command the repositories were being checked out but not visible in IDE. I needed to add [workspaceLocation](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/multi-repo)
property and another file project.code-worskpace to specify the folders.

Example
workspaceLocation:
myRepo/.gitpod/project.code-workspace

project.code-workspace

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "../"
        },
        {
            "path": "../../repo1"
        },
        {
            "path": "../../repo2"
        },
        {
            "path": "../../repo3"
        },
        {
            "path": "../../repo4"
        },
    ]
}
```